# Does django-mptt support nested models?

Tags: django, tree, django-mptt

I have a database of nested entities, that actually address parts: **Street-House-Technical Room.** In other words, I'd like to have a tree of nodes with different attributes on each level.

What I'd like to implement is to use django-mptt features for this database, for example, I want to see the database as a tree in Django Admin.

I tried the following in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class Street(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='streets')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class House(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(Street, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='houses')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TechRoom(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='tech_rooms')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and my admin.py looks as:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin

from places.models import Street, House, TechRoom

admin.site.register(Street, MPTTModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(House, MPTTModelAdmin)
admin.site.register(TechRoom, MPTTModelAdmin)
```

The problem is it works as a regular Foreign key not as a tree.
Is it possible to implement nested models using django-mptt?
More specifically is it possible to use a model name (e.g. Street) instead of 'self' here:

parent = TreeForeignKey(**Street**, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='houses')

Comment: Exactly what features do you want to use you can't with a *simple* `ForeignKey`? Django-mptt is to work with the same model, so a real tree, this seems to be a three-level tree.

Comment: I want to have a tree but with a different list of attributes on every level of the tree. Also, I want to have a tree in Django Admin as well as to implement search among nodes of several levels. Django-mptt offers a lot of useful features beyond a Foreign Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the required solution. It is the [django-polymorphic-tree](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic-tree) library.
The author says:

> You can write Django models that form a tree structure where each node
> can be a different model type.

And it works.